# OpenStreetMap: CRS not matching

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, openstreetmap

I have different layers with different CRS, I think therefore the layers don't match. But I don't know how to fix this. Here is what I did (QGIS 3.0.1 on Debian Buster).

I connected to OpenStreetMap Tile Server `https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` to request XYZ Tiles. This is the first layer.

The tile server uses the CRS `WGS 84, Pseudo Mercator Projection EPSG 3857`.

Now, I tried to built my own map, by doing a quick query with QuickOSM. Key is `building`, querying `Extent of the map canvas` (coordinates are 300.000, 6.100.000, Scale is 1:60.000, which is in France, somewhere south of Paris).

This gives me three additional layers, all called `OsmQuery`, see image.

[image]

The additional layers use CRS `WGS 84 EPSG:4326`. If you look at the map, you see the buildings belonging to Chateau-Landon (south) near La Madeleine-sur-Loing (north). The destinations are about 7km apart.

My thinking is: "The error might result from different projections. However, 7km is a lot. I find it kind of strange that OpenStreetMap uses two different CRS." But I'm quite a newbie...

What can I do to get an exact match of all the layers?

My QGIS version is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Try setting your project CRS to the same as the tiles and enable On The Fly reprojection.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't enable On The Fly reprojection in 3.0.1. I amended my original question regarding this fact. Maybe the feature disappeared in 3.0.1?

Comment: "Disabling on the fly projection is no longer an option in QGIS 3.0" (https://issues.qgis.org/issues/11644)

Comment: Same here, looks like a bug. If I save the buildings to geopackage and open the file in QGIS 2.18, buildings and background fit as expected.

Comment: The problem went away for me after updating from QGIS 3.0.0 to 3.0.1 (on Windows 7 and Linux Mint with Ubuntugis dependencies).

Comment: @AndreJ: I have been already running QGIS 3.0.1 on Linux Debian (buster). I updated the question with my exact version. As hinted by https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/issues/834, maybe PROJ can be the reason. Can you please compare your versions to mine?

Comment: On Windows, I have proj 4.9.3, but GDAL 2.2.4. On Ubuntu, proj 4.9.2 and GDAL 2.2.2. So no chance with the proj 5.0.0 error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by AndreJ, I also did an `apt-get upgrade`, resulting in the following versions:

[image]

After the update, everything now works as expected. If I'm going to the same coordinates `(300.000, 6.100.000)` in EPSG 3857, scale `1:60.000` as before, I'm now landing at a slightly different location, south of Chalette-sur-Loing, approximately 25km more to the south as before. Hence the problem had something to do with a bug in EPSG 3857.

As the difference before between EPSG 3857 and EPSG:4326 was 7km, I think the bug wasn't confined to EPSG 3857 but maybe a general projection problem.

As the QGIS code revision remained the same, it was no QGIS problem. "Running against GDAL/OGR" changed from `2.2.3` to `2.2.4` and "Running against PROJ" changed from `5.0.0` to `5.0.1`.

According to https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/issues/834, the problem might have been with PROJ.

Assuming QGIS uses `cs2cs` from PROJ to convert between CRS, the problem can be boiled down to the command line as follows (everything should be written in one line):

```
echo 300000 6100000 | cs2cs 
+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs 
+to 
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
-f %.12f
```

The correct version of PROJ should result in:

```
2.694945852359  47.958779800526 0.000000000000
```

But I don't mind anymore - everything works now as it is supposed to be now. Great software!