# Basemap error offset for QuickMapServices QGIS 3.0.0. in Windows

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, quickmapservices

I noticed an offset error for all basemaps provided by Quickmapservices in Qgis 3.0.0 installed in Windows. It was installed with the setup.exe application (advanced options, 4 GB after installed). The offset error is of about 47 km measured from north to south. Does anyone notice the same error and have an easy fix for it? I reinstalled this plugin several times but the error persists. Any solution is very welcomed.

Comment: There was an error in QGIS 3.0.0 which was fixed in QGIS 3.0.1. Which one are you running?

Comment: 3.0.0., I will update it and check again, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278588/openstreetmap-crs-not-matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade the QGIS version (e.g., QGIS 3.0.2.), thanks to @AndreJ.